# How to make first option of <select > selected with Quickbase?

Tags: quickbase

I have tried research on the net, but nothing.
I think the solutions will be in javasript.
I have tried img's onload event but it is not stable.
Do I have to wait until the developers at Quickbase maybe code it?
Any idea?

(PS: not page site at home what I would like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and the result is a bad thing. Unfortunately nowadays there is no any way to select any option to default. We have to wait while the developers at quickbase solve this issue.